# RTP receiver sample issue

Tags: kurento

I have an issue with the kurento java tutorial RTP receiver: web client (Firefox 62) never receives video data.
Java endpoint seems ok but in kms log file I can see this:

```
warning rtpsource  rtpsource.c:983 calculate_jitter()  cannot get clock-rate for pt 14
warning rtpjitterbuffer  gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2833 gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain() <rtpjitterbuffer2>  No clock-rate in caps!, dropping buffer
```

To generate rtp video, I use VLC (Sample RTP sender given in the web page seems not working).
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (virtual machine from osboxes)

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

i failed to make the rtp receiver example running correctly too. but i find it worked when "Sender uses SRTP" checked,  try the "Sample SRTP sender" stated at the bottom of the page   then you can find the video appeared.

Comment: I also wasn't able to get a single RTP endpoint to work using VLC. However, the example Sample SRTP sender command did work to play back from macos given the ports returned by the page and a correct full local path to a video.